# How to format a string for a textview android

Tags: android, string, encode, formatting

I have a TextView and when I call .setText(string), it displays the string exactly as it is.
For instance, if the string contains " ' " , `&#39;` will be displayed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide a complete example that illustrates the problem you have encountered. The example should only include code relevant to the current question and should not introduce any unrelated compiler errors.

Comment: To address your question, are you *sure* that the string contains a literal apostrophe? Or does it contain the sequence "&#39;" which represents an apostrophe in some situations. From what you have here, it sounds like the later is true and you will need find a way to display the literal apostrophe in your `TextView`.

Comment: I have mentioned everything that was relevant.

I have a String and when I try to set the text of the TextView, there is no problem. The problem arises when I execute the code:
The String is not displayed as it should. The quote appears as &#39; instead of  just '

Comment: I am trying to help you and would like more information. If you are unwilling to provide that information requested, then you have wasted my time as well as your own. Maybe someone else can guess at the solution that you need.

Comment: I suggest that you use a debugger to view the **actual** contents of the String source, which I suspect are not what you think they are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like your outside source already does the convertion from `'` to `&#39;` since regular single quote will be displayed just fine in a `TextView`. What you can to do in this case is:

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(stringSource));
```

where `stringSource` is your string that comes from outside source. This will take care of more than just the single quote character.

Comment: But Html.fromHtml(stringSource) returns a Spanned object instead of a string. What to do with it, so I can get the formatted string?

Comment: Done. I didn't know that Spanned implements CharSequence. 

Thank you very much for your answer, it helped me a great deal :)

Answer (score 1):

The single quote ' in java needs to be escaped using a backslash (\). You can find other characters that need to be escaped [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Comment: The string is read at runtime from an outside source.
I have no way of knowing what characters will be inside.

Other ideas?